# How can change color of plotted line in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using arrow.m for a line with direction. I don't how to change color of line when using arrow.m. the original line's properties doesn't work. If you have any suggestion please advice me?

link of arrow.m

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m

Comment: Could you paste/copy the arrow.m file?

Comment: From the comments on that page:

"...It's also not obvious that the arrow will be a patch object, so has properties like edgecolor, facecolor, rather than line properties. -- Jo Williams"

Comment: @chessbot, I'm new in Matlab, but in some point of file we can find this:  ARROW(H,'Prop1',PropVal1,...), where H is a vector of handles to previously-created arrows and/or line objects, will update the previously
created arrows according to the current view and any specified properties, and will convert two-point line objects to corresponding arrows.  ARROW(H) will update the arrows if the current view has changed.  Root, figure, or axes handles included in H are replaced by all descendant Arrow objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the comments on the link of the arrow.m file :

```
%Here goes the view setting 
view([1 1 1])

arrow([0 0 0],xvector, 'EdgeColor','k','FaceColor','k') 
arrow([0 0 0],yvector, 'EdgeColor','b','FaceColor','b') 
arrow([0 0 0],zvector, 'EdgeColor','r','FaceColor','r')
```

You should try to play with the `EdgeColor` and the `FaceColor` parameters after the `view([...])` command

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying the arrow's `EdgeColor`:

```
h = arrow([0 0], [2 3]);
set(h, 'EdgeColor', [1 0 0]); // the line is now red
set(h, 'FaceColor', [0 1 0]); // the arrowhead is now green
```